# None value added to JSON API result

Tags: python, python-requests

I call a REST API.
Result type is a json format.

Response header content:

```
{'Server': 'nginx/1.14.2', 'Date': 'Fri, 05 Mar 2021 19:49:31 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'Pss-Api-Version': '1.20.1', 'Pss-Engine-Version': '6.0.2', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=63072000'}
None
```

As you can see, a `None` value is added to headers.
And I find it in response json content:

```
<Response [200]>
None
```

Is it the same `None`?
How to explain it and how to remove the `None` field in response?

Comment: Please show us the full code you have already tried, and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code that prints those 2 lines